# Simple trigonometric derivation in cathode ray tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

I want to calculate the distance from the origin where the electrons hit the screen:
[image]

I've got:

$$\begin{align} 
&s_1  = v\,t_1\\ \\
&s_2 = v\,t_2 \\ \\
&y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\,a_y\,t_1^2 = \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\left(\frac{s_1}{v}\right)^2 \quad \text{where $d$ is the distance between the plates} \\\\
&y_2 = v_y\,t_2 = a_y\,t_1\,t_2 = \frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\frac{s_1}{v}\,\frac{s_2}{v}
\\\\
&\text{hence} \quad l = y_1+y_2 \\ \\
& l = \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\left(\frac{s_1}{v}\right)^2+ \frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\frac{s_1}{v}\,\frac{s_2}{v} = \frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\frac{s_1}{v^2}\,\left(\frac{s_1}{2}+s_2\right)
\end{align}$$

Now I tried the same thing with trigonometry because it seems way shorter:
$$\begin{align}&\tan\alpha = \frac{y_1}{s_1} = \frac{l}{s_1+s_2}\quad\Rightarrow \\\\
&l = \frac{y_1\,(s_1+s_2)}{s_1} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\left(\frac{s_1}{v}\right)^2 }{s_1}\,(s_1+s_2) =\frac{U\,q}{d\,m}\,\frac{s_1}{v^2}\,\left(\frac{s_1+s_2}{2}\right)\end{align}$$

What seems almost like the same expression despite of $s_2/2$ what's bothering me. U know what went wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $y_1=\frac12 a_yt_1^2$?

Comment: As your diagram correctly shows, the trajectory over $s_1$ is a parabola. You can't determine a single $\alpha$. $\alpha$ varies as the electron advances through the $s_1$ zone.

Comment: Yep, with the formula now being right it seems abstruse to chose a fixed angel alpha, even if it has almost came off.

Comment: I think your first derivation is correct, so stick with that. All the best.